# Is there a way to compare contents of Enums in python?

Tags: python, enums

I have 2 enums as below:

```
class flower1(Enum):
    Jasmine = "Jasmine"
    Rose = "Rose"
    Lily = "Lily"


class flower2(Enum):
    Jasmine = "Jasmine"
    Sunflower="Sun flower"
    Lily = "Lily"
```

how to find if the enum values are equal and if not find diff of contents in the above two enums?

Comment: Please add some precisions. What is the expected output ? What happens if flower1 contains an attribute `Flower1 = "Flower"` and flower2 an attribute `Flower2 = "Flower"` and what happens if flower1 contains `Flower = "Flower1"` and flower2 contains `Flower = "Flower2"`?

Comment: @CorentinLimier,sorry for not adding more clarity to ques. Its more about, to compare and get if the values of these enums equal each other or not and if any new additions/deletions in enum2, return the diff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Enum`s are directly iterable, so if you only need the difference and not which Enum has which member, you can do:

```
>>> set([m.name for m in flower1]) & set([m.name for m in flower2])
set(['Jasmine', 'Lily'])
```